# LIKE operator isn't working properly

Tags: php, sql, sql-like

I'm trying to update some values in a database, the main table where I get the value to update have this structure:

`http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/403/leagueTable` 
so in the update query I execute this statement:

```
UPDATE leaguetable SET matchDay = ?, position = ?, teamName = ?, 
playedGames = ?, points = ?, goals = ?, goalsAgainst = ?, 
goalDifference = ?, self = ?, soccerSeason = ?, team = ? WHERE
self LIKE 'http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/403/leagueTable'"
```

this query is correct but when I try it in the console of PhpMyAdmin it returns `0 rows` because the value `self` have this structure:

```
http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/403/leagueTable/?matchday=2
```

What am I doing wrong in the like attribute?

**Note**: I pass the value `http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/403/leagueTable` in a variable called `$x`, in the post the link is just an example for show the layout of the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the wildcard character `%` for it to work.

Read more about it here [MSDN LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

Specifically about the wildcard character `%`

`'http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/403/leagueTable%'` finds all URL's beginning with the given, including the desired `/?matchday=2`.

In your code:

```
UPDATE leaguetable 
SET matchDay = ?, position = ?, teamName = ?, playedGames = ?, points = ?, goals = ?, goalsAgainst = ?, goalDifference = ?, self = ?, soccerSeason = ?, team = ?    
WHERE self LIKE 'http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/403/leagueTable%'
```

Answer (score 4):

try with an % (wildcard) after it:

```
UPDATE leaguetable SET matchDay = ?, position = ?, teamName = ?, 
        playedGames = ?, points = ?, goals = ?, goalsAgainst = ?, 
        goalDifference = ?, self = ?, soccerSeason = ?, team = ?    WHERE self     LIKE 'http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/403/leagueTable%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use wildcard character to get the output

```
UPDATE leaguetable SET matchDay = ?, position = ?, teamName = ?, 
playedGames = ?, points = ?, goals = ?, goalsAgainst = ?, 
goalDifference = ?, self = ?, soccerSeason = ?, team = ?    WHERE self LIKE 'http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/403/leagueTable%'"
```